# What happened to IndexBuilder.HasFilter?

Tags: entity-framework-core

`IndexBuilder<TEntity>` in EFCore 7 had a [HasFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalindexbuilderextensions.hasfilter?view=efcore-7.0) method, but the following code does not compile in ef-core 8.

```cs
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DomainEvent> builder)
    {
        builder.HasIndex(x => x.CreatedUtc);
        builder
            .HasIndex(x => x.PublishedUtc)
            .HasFilter($"{nameof(DomainEvent.PublishedUtc)} is null");
    }
```

> 'IndexBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'HasFilter' and no accessible extension method 'HasFilter' accepting a first argument of type 'IndexBuilder'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you added a specific database provider: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

I believe these extensions are in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational package so you could also add https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/ but adding a specific database provider should also work.

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing. Thank you!